# I can't review for two days after failing one audit

Tags: support, review, review-audits, review-suspension

I was reviewing Low Quality Answers and I failed an audit (I kind of think the audit was wrong, but this isn't what this is about. Then again, I may have just made a mistake).

I was a bit shocked to see that since that one failed audit, I can no longer review **anything** for two days. When clicking to review, I get:

"You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might need a break. Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing."

So, why was I blocked from reviewing for two days after just one audit? Kind of sucks, because tomorrow I should be getting a gold badge for Suggested Edits :D.

I've [looked at this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177073/cant-do-reviews-after-failing-1-audit).

Comment: No, it's not one. You probably don't (want to) remember the other audits you failed. Community Manager can see your audit history and confirm this, but from such reports posted here on Meta from time to time there's **always** more than one failed audit.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd How can I check? I barely remember failing any. I'm just basing this on what I remember. Maybe I did fail some recent ones?

Comment: No way to check, I fear... it's not visible anywhere to ordinary users and even moderators as far as I can tell. Note that it's "cross queue" i.e. maybe you failed audits in other review queues.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd So... do I have to just wait 2 days now :(?

Comment: Either that, or wait for community manager (e.g. Anna Lear or Tim Post) who can lift such a ban.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd maybe an expensive web crawler that visits the user's reviews one by one would do? I'm willing to write one.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Alright, thanks for your support :)

Comment: @Jan no, the audits are not listed there to begin with. You will have to crawl all existing reviews i.e. `http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/xxx` which will probably be blocked by the server.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Quick question, because I noticed the other question I linked had this: How can I find a link to the audit?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I can go from http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-post/history . That's a lot of links (20 links per day of history for not too many days), however, so I'm wondering what rate-limiting strategy should I implement (will "no concurrent requests" suffice?)

Comment: @Jan the history is visible only to 10K users, other users will just see their own review history; bot/crawler will see nothing.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd the asker would have to run the script, then. I intended to write it as a page script anyways.

Comment: @Haidro like I said before, community manager can see a list of each user audit history and Anna Lear is such a manager.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Actually, the activity tab in a user's profile lists each review.

Comment: @Manishearth Not audits it seems

Comment: @Manishearth audits are either stored in separate place or hidden on purpose, maybe to not "shame" the users, same way the deleted posts are not listed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd at least for some reviews, audits are shown in the history.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd oic. Didn't know that :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/users/1971805/haidro?tab=activity&sort=reviews for the history of all your reviews, including all audits

Comment: @gnat I don't see any audits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You failed two *reopen* audits (the second failure got you a two-day ban) and one *first-post* audit which also got you a two-day ban.

I guess you were somewhat unlucky to get posts in your audits which are not *totally* obvious.

Anyway, you don't seem to be a robo-reviewer so I lifted the ban.

Comment: With the AI these days, you can never know for sure... ;-)