# 2-day ban dispute

Tags: support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I have been banned for reviewing for 2 days by the auto-ban. I was given a message that said that I had failed too many recent audits - though I have not used the site in over a week, and this is the first failed audit I remember in about 2 weeks.

I just want to know if it is possible to reverse this auto-ban, as I believe it has been erroneously triggered (or at least, triggered in such a way that it seems to me illogical)

Related question: [Can't do reviews after failing 1 audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177073/cant-do-reviews-after-failing-1-audit)

**Edit:**

I am not sure why there is so much negativity in the comments and answers to my question here. I am not the first person to ever fail an audit, it happens, and sometimes it sucks. And as I understand it, StackOverflow is build on the principle that each action is treated independently.

Yes, I failed an audit, I made a mistake, and I am glad that it was an audit so that the vandalism would not get into SO - If you check my records, my activity, you will see I am a serious member here and I strive to try to make things right here.

I expected to get some good advise, some explanation, and hoped to get a repeal of my 2-day ban. This outright *attack* on me for failing an audit is uncalled for, and very immature, especially all the down-voting, what exactly is bad about *the question*? it seems like a straightforward question with many like it - that all have upvotes, and not downvotes. Am I such an evil anomaly as to deserve all this hate? Is this the constructive website to which I belong?

Comment: If the answer in your link is anything to go by, not only failed audits count (and you have to admit that [the last one is a pretty bad one to fail on](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2725410) ), but also the speed with which you review. Looking at the timestamps on some of your suggested edit reviews, you breeze through them pretty quickly. Perhaps that has contributed as well. And it seems that audits up to a month back are taken into account.

Comment: To be honest, why not take a break from reviewing and come back in two days? It's not the end of the world, really.

Comment: I'm really curious. What made you approve [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2725410)? This alone deserve long review ban, in my opinion. If I were to judge, I would *extend* your ban, not reverse it.

Comment: Yes - I understand it is a horrible audit to fail on. But I did fail it. Yes - I was not paying attention, and I was very happy that it was an audit so that this horribly edit would not really get approved, but also - I am concerned why it banned me for 2 days while stating "recent audit failures" where I have not failed an audit for over 2 weeks I think.

Comment: @InbarRose I don't understand your comment - you appear to have failed that audit [38 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2725410). And "not paying attention" it not acceptable when it comes to reviewing, hence the ban punishment.

Comment: Yes, that is what caused teh ban.... I am talking before that.

Comment: @DuncanJones - I think the dispute is "recent audit failures"  vs "recent audit failure"

Comment: You're probably getting downvoted for asking whether *"it is possible to reverse this auto-ban"* – people are obviously disagreeing with you.

Comment: *"(...)especially all the down-voting, what exactly is bad about the question?"*  Downvotes are different on meta, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92745/186983

Comment: Of note @Matsemann, that has recently been changed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191880/161198

Comment: Well, I have been sorely let-down by the community that I had previously felt highly motivated to assist. I have been severely disappointed, and that is going to effect me. I shouldn't be surprised, but I am.

Comment: @InbarRose Perhaps a (community-)moderator can provide a bit more insight into the full extent of audits that caused this ban. It's unfortunate, but it's only 2 days. And admittedly you could spend a bit more time on each one. Just take 2 days off and then get back to it. Until then, just wait for some more official information.

Comment: @Bart That is my plan, this post is just to try to understand why it happened after only 1 failure in over a week, and possibly revoke it for being erroneous. I was considering posting it as a bug-report because the wording of the ban was such that it seems wrong. But I decided on a support post because I didn't know enough. Had I known how negative people would be, I think it would have been better for everyone to just ignore it - but then - nothing ever happens, which is why negativity is bad - it scares away change.

Comment: I'm citing this post as an example of how people are oblivious to the effect of their tone. People on Meta need to realize that _our stereotypical biting sarcasm hurts_. Be aware of the subtleties of your tone, and read your comments back as someone who is five times as sensitive as you. You'll find there's a lot more hostility in the Meta tone than seems at first glance. I direct this at nobody in particular, and some are better than others. Still, _be sensitive with your wordings, please_.

Comment: If you had only asked about why the ban happened, without asking for the ban to be reversed, I assume this would have played out differently. I agree the accusations of robo-reviewing are a little over board here and it could have probably been a little more civilized.

Comment: @slhck Meta still needs to watch its tone even if the OP is obviously incorrect or disagreed-with. We're here for _support_, and we set the tone for all of StackExchange. Our comments and responses are why people feel Stack Overflow is hostile. Anyway, we're getting off topic. I'll be in chat tomorrow if the thread is worth continuing.

Comment: @Emrakul Maybe if we just [changed our logo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/m0PeI.jpg) people would be less likely to get confused?

Comment: @Emrakul This is not a question of correctness. The OP wasn't *incorrect* per se – they didn't make any wrong assumptions, etc. They just asked for something the community didn't want them to have. Hence the downvotes.

Comment: @Cody I think you may have missed my point. Still, this is not the place for this discussion.

Comment: @Inbar Rose:" am not sure why there is so much negativity in the comments and answers to my question here. I am not the first person to ever fail an audit, it happens"
You want to know why? Just look at people in this post. Most these are people who always vote together and always follow each other.

Comment: @Inbar Rose:" you seem to be an experienced user. By this time you should know that any type of criticism of the SO system gives you heavy downvote.

Comment: Sorry for the dogpile of downvotes on your question.  Everyone fails audits at one time or another, some are quite subjective, and mistakes can be made even when they're not.  [An example of subjective problems.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169580/13295)

Comment: @SNash Could you stop your unnecessary bashing of SO/SE? We all know by now that you prefer EE. But that doesn't mean you have to drag other users down with you in your spiral of negativity. Yes, I feel the voting was somewhat overblown here (I don't really see the need for downvotes in this case, but that's just me perhaps). But your doomsday scenarios of the OP being downvoted until he is post-banned are not grounded in fact. With the OP's participation history here on Meta, he will be just fine.

Comment: @Bart Statistics and "Facts" speak for itself. Just compare number  of questions with critisim which got downvote with those which got upvote...

You can't hide the facts.

Comment: @Bart: If I do constructive  criticism of SO it's not called bashing. If any forum/website is Not open to criticism it is doomed to failure. For the good of SO, the attitude of zero tolerance for any criticism should end.

Comment: There is nothing constructive about your criticism @SNash. If anything, it's poisonous and harmful.

Comment: @Bart: you claiming my criticism is not constructive does not hide the facts.
Why it is poisonous ? because "YOU" think SO is perfect?

Answer (score 20):

You did 5-7 reviews per minute, which suggests that you're *not paying attention*. Failing the obvious audit proves that you're going too fast. I feel the system is working as it should.

Comment: True. At last we see robo reviewers falling down! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd and whining about that :-)

Comment: I am sorry that you guys feel that way. But when you have done so many reviews as I have - you can see quickly if they are good or bad, especially when its formatting of code - or typo fixing. Takes only a few seconds. But yes - I suppose sometimes I might miss something, but its not intentional.

Comment: @Inbar no, what you are doing is pure and simple robo reviewing, which is not accepted. Reviewer is expected to pay attention.

Comment: @InbarRose umm... if you miss such obvious vandalism, you _need_ to slow down

Comment: Looking at some of your non-review approvals that were approved on a 3-2 vote makes me worry more than a couple of audits, honestly.

Comment: @ Matsemann aned Wooble: Give me a Break!!! doing 5-6 review by and expert is not neccassarily bad. Just explian what's the point of pissing off a super contirbutor like @InbarRose ? Take a look at main , this person is an expert in various fields. Stop pissing people off and make them run to other computer Q/A sites. Who said SO rules should not be changed?

Comment: @SNash I really hope that's a joke. Even assuming he is "an expert in various fields" (I glanced at his rep. It's high, but then he could be rep farming, or just ask a lot of questions, or... etc., and I'm not going to bother to check), that has no relevance here. How good someone is as a moderator depends only upon how good their work **as a moderator** is shown to be. If Alan Turing himself rose from the grave tomorrow and started moderating SO, but was terrible at it, he shouldn't moderate. Simple as that. Plus, less time moderating means more time breaking Nazi codes. Win-win in my book.

Comment: @root, what you are saying seem like a joke to me. Why anyone in the right mind spend his/her valuable time to "Farm" SO rep which is basicaly worthless.

Comment: @SNash ```Why anyone in the right mind spend his/her valuable time to "Farm" SO rep which is basicaly worthless. ``` Ah. You see, we come from two different schools of philosophical thought. When you come in contact with a complete stranger, you start from the assumption that they are in their right mind, that their time is valuable, and that their priorities are in more or less logical order. I, on the other hand, don't.