# "You have failed too many recent review audits"

Tags: support, review-audits

I know there are a lot of questions about this issue already - but now I have experienced it myself and I am a kind of baffled. I simply don't understand the system. There is no place other than this to raise my incomprehension issue.

Today I (also) experienced :

> You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might
>   need a break. Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

After one apparently "wrong" audit, which I by the way didn't understand should be wrong at all. Of course I have failed audits before, once in a while, and I have made mistakes after reviewing thousands of post in all the categories. But what's making me wonder most, is *why* it is coming now, when I have passed all audits in the past 4 or 5 days, without a single "stop and listen"-message?

Could the moderators look into this?

I appreciate the system, and if I am wrong I am wrong. And to me a pause is good. I just do not understand why my quarantine comes now, when I actually have passed all the audits except one, and not the day where I didn't pass 5 times.

I can understand "too many", but not "too many **recent**".

I post this because I have read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177073/cant-do-reviews-after-failing-1-audit) post, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188894/review-ban-after-skipping-a-review) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) (to clarification) post already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree, [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4041066) was pretty borderline, because without the context of the rest of the question it might look like an attempt at a comment. Your previous audit failures might have worked against you in this case.

I looked over your recent reviews and didn't see any real problems, so I've lifted the ban. If you feel that this shouldn't have been an audit test case, may I plug [this feature request of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790) for users to be able to contest borderline audits?

As far as the wording goes, that even shows to users that moderators have manually banned from review, but who may not have failed any audits, so it doesn't always reflect the exact situation. I could see using variable or more generic wording there, but I don't know how high of a priority that would be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4041142 "looks good"? OP could at least have fixed the broken code formatting there.

Comment: True @Wooble, but review-ban-worthy? Meh.

Comment: Thank you, @Brad Larson.

Comment: @Wooble, is it not another person who has made a bad try of editing afterwards? Trying to format code correct is the main thing I really look for as a "action" I can perform when auditing first posts. I cannot remember this case exactly, but it seems also weird to me I should have overlooked such a obvious chance for increasing my "Edited posts" account. If not, it is proofed that I do need a good long review-vacation.

Comment: @BradLarson wow that happened to me today to. I did not make many reviews in the past days and the last fail should be 1 or 2 weeks ago. Now i am "banned" for 1 month. Why so long? Until now i fialed only 2 or 3 review tests, as much as i remember. One of those was a high quality post, of a theme i don't know much about and i only clicked "comment". So i don't understand why i am "banned" til Apr 26. Can you please have a look at it and tell me?

Comment: @Springrbua - In your case, I personally banned you from review because you approved clear spam: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4317665 and allowed it to live on the site for weeks. When reviewing First Posts or Late Answers, you have one job above all else, and that's to prevent spam or trolling from making it onto the site. If it's any consolation, you weren't the only one I banned from review for doing this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227105/135615

Comment: @BradLarson i can't see this answer anymore as it is deleted. So i can't tell you why i did not mark it as spam. I only know, that i always try to give my best and if you take a look at my flags, there are 15/15 helpful. If you look at the reviews you see, that i almost always leave a comment to let new users know how to behave. If i did not mark this spam it will probably be, cause i don't have enough knowledge in this theme and then i agree, i should have clicked on the `skip` button. Is there a way to show me this answer. I would like to know my fail. Thanks

Comment: @Springrbua - This is an image of the review: http://i.stack.imgur.com/l3edC.png . That was an ad, not an answer. You need to be extremely careful when reviewing items in the First Posts and Late Answers queues. If I catch anyone approving spam, they are instantly banned from review. Too much spam has been approved in review lately, and it's harming the site.

Comment: @BradLarson ah okay the question about the migration from thunderbird to outlook. I remember, that i ve read that but i thought that in this case a tool to do that won't be that bad. I did not know that this is also kind of spam, as i saw things like this on many other questions. But in this case also the question itself was not correct wasn't it?
Anyways thanks for pointing that. Its important that there are people like you to keep the quality up. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BradLarson just a little question. If i don't understand the theme of the question/answer should i stil try to evaluate the content or is it better to use the `skip` button then? Its important for me to know such things so i am ready to review again after this month.